# Select from array

Tags: javascript

I have an array. How can I get the name of all users whose group contains "confluence-developers"?

```
const users = [ {
  "name" : "Mako",
  "email" : "mail1@mail.com",
  "admin" : false,
  "profileUpdatable" : false,
  "internalPasswordDisabled" : true,
  "groups" : [ "readers" ]
}, {
  "name" : "Arasy",
  "email" : "mail2@mail.com",
  "admin" : false,
  "profileUpdatable" : false,
  "internalPasswordDisabled" : true,
  "groups" : [ "confluence-users", "readers", "confluence-developers" ]
}, {
  "name" : "Eliza",
  "email" : "mail3@mail.com",
  "admin" : false,
  "profileUpdatable" : false,
  "internalPasswordDisabled" : true,
  "groups" : [ "readers", "confluence-users" ]
}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `filter()`, then `map()`:

```js
const users = [ {
  "name" : "Mako",
  "email" : "mail1@mail.com",
  "admin" : false,
  "profileUpdatable" : false,
  "internalPasswordDisabled" : true,
  "groups" : [ "readers" ]
}, {
  "name" : "Arasy",
  "email" : "mail2@mail.com",
  "admin" : false,
  "profileUpdatable" : false,
  "internalPasswordDisabled" : true,
  "groups" : [ "confluence-users", "readers", "confluence-developers" ]
}, {
  "name" : "Eliza",
  "email" : "mail3@mail.com",
  "admin" : false,
  "profileUpdatable" : false,
  "internalPasswordDisabled" : true,
  "groups" : [ "readers", "confluence-users" ]
}]

const confluence_user_names = users
  .filter(user => user.groups.includes('confluence-users'))
  .map(user => user.name);

console.log(confluence_user_names);
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this can help

```
const confluence_developers = users.filter(user => user.groups.includes('confluence-developers'))
```

Comment: Thank!
How can I see it through display.log?

display.log(confluence_developers): [[object Object]]

Comment: @AndreyMolfly dont know display.log command, maybe you cab use console.log?

Answer (score 1):

There a lot of ways you can archive this in javascript with higher order functions, like @connexo mentioned, `filter()`, then `map()`.

Another option is use `reduce()` :

```
const confluence_user_names = users.reduce((names, info) => {
   if(info.groups.includes('confluence-users')) {
     return info.name
   }
}, [])
```

Comment: Thank!
How can I see it through display.log?
display.log(confluence_user_names)
undefined

Answer (score 0):

You could take a single loop with [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and look for nested groups.

```js
var data = [{ name: "Mako", email: "mail1@mail.com", admin: false, profileUpdatable: false, internalPasswordDisabled: true, groups: ["readers"] }, { name: "Arasy", email: "mail2@mail.com", admin: false, profileUpdatable: false, internalPasswordDisabled: true, groups: ["confluence-users", "readers", "confluence-developers"] }, { name: "Eliza", email: "mail3@mail.com", admin: false, profileUpdatable: false, internalPasswordDisabled: true, groups: ["readers", "confluence-users"] }],
    group = "confluence-users",
    result = data.flatMap(({ name, groups }) => groups.includes(group) ? name : []);
    
console.log(result);
```